# Is it allowed to access `GenServer`'s defstruct data from handle_call etc function?

Tags: elixir

If some properties have been added to defstruct, is it possible for `handle_call` function to access these data without explicit pass through parameter?

Is there any data like `me` for accessing?

Nx project's stream file, defstruct here has 3 item (:pid, :input,:output)

[image]

handle_call here, it is possible to access the above items without explicit pass of parameter?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but if you're asking whether Elixir has anything like Python's `self` or Java's `this`, the answer is no. There is no way to write a function *inside* of a struct construct. `defstruct` defines a structure, and all of your functions are at the module level. The fact that a structure, at least superficially, shares a name with a structure is merely syntactic convenience

Comment: I have updated the above by adding the example.

Comment: Then the answer is no. There *is* no implicit object. `handle_call` is just a function, not a method on a class like in Python. Any arguments must be just that: arguments. Elixir is *not* an object-oriented programming language, so I recommend you forget a lot of the OOP patterns you know if you want to succeed in Elixir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GenServer` process has a state, which is passed through the following chain of calls:

`start_link/3` →‍ `init/1` → [`handle_continue/2`] → `handle_×××/{2,3}` → `terminate/1`

This state is managed by the virtual machine and that’s how stateful objects (e. g. processes in the actor model) exist. The return value of all the functions above is the new state of the process (well, one element of the tuple returned.)

---

Struct is just a struct, it’s an [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) term, like list, or atom, or map (and they *are* indeed maps underneath.) There is no difference between `:foo` term, and `%{foo: :bar}` term, and `%Baz{foo: :bar}` term from the point of view of their lifecycle. They got created immutable and garbage collected after no one needs them anymore. They are just terms, bulk of static data.

Whether one needs to carry a struct through a lifecycle of the process, it should be put into process’ state, that’s it.

Comment: I understand `struct` usage now.

Comment: Nice to hear; glad to be of any help.